# Error: "redeclare" annotation is undefined -Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, annotations, overriding, redeclare

I'm trying to use 'redeclare' annotation inside extension type in dart

```
extension type MyString(String _) implements String {
  // Replaces 'String.operator[]'
  @redeclare
  int operator [](int index) => codeUnitAt(index);
}
```

but it give me this error

> Undefined name 'redeclare' used as an annotation. Try defining the
> name or importing it from another library.

Any idea how I can fix the problem ?

The sdk version in my device: Dart SDK version: 3.3.0 (stable)

Comment: The [`@redeclare` annotation](https://pub.dev/documentation/meta/latest/meta/redeclare-constant.html) is from [`package:meta`](https://pub.dev/packages/meta).